# Java bytecode - checking if args is equal to null, will it ever run

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Got a java class and got it to bytecode. My question is will it ever go to _L2 based on the below? I wouldn't have thought so (I read another StackOverflow article that said it would never be null but I can't find it right now)

Secondly, if it does go to _L1, it just sets j to zero.... but what is the next step? Does it continue to _L7?

If it does hit _L2 where does it go from there?

```
public class testing

{

    public static volatile void main(String args[])
    {
        local;
        Object obj;
        int i;
        obj = ((String) (obj)).toCharArray();
        i = 0;
        if(args == null) goto _L2; else goto _L1
    _L1:
        int j = 0;
    _L7:
        if(j == -(~obj.length + 2)) goto _L4; else goto _L3
    _L2:
        if(args[0].length() != 32)
            break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_484;
```

Comment: You can call the method with `testing.main(null);`, so it can jump to `_L2`.

Answer (score 1):

`args` won't be null when you invoke the program normally, but one could always call the `main` method manually with a null argument.

That being said, the code you posted doesn't make much sense. Technically, *the entire method* is unreachable because the line `obj = ((String) (obj)).toCharArray();` at the beginning will unconditionally throw, since `obj` is null here.

My guess is that it was obfuscated and that the decompiler you used is not decompiling it accurately. Instead of using a possibly buggy decompiler, I'd recommend using the [Krakatau disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) and posting the bytecode disassembly so we can see what is actually in the classfile in question.

Comment: Actually, the variable `obj` is uninitialized at this point, not even containing `null`, so the code wouldn’t pass the verifier. But it’s indeed very likely that the actual code looks different and this is the result of obfuscation *and* a flawed decompiler.

Comment: Good point. I forgot that variables have to be initialized, unlike fields. I guess that means the code wouldn't even compile and so there's no way to talk about what it's runtime behavior is (not that it would compile anyway with all those gotos in there).

Comment: …and the `volatile` modifier at a method and the nonsensical statement `local;`. These are indicators to me that regardless of the obfuscation that apparently has been applied to the bytecode, the decompiler isn’t very sophisticated in general.